# What does 'isolation' mean in a radar antenna system spec text? How to measure it?

Tags: antenna

It says "85 dB minimum at 18 inch centerline-to-centerline over the OFR". What does it mean? How do I measure that isolation value? in this [Text](https://teldatasystem.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/8203-1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

"Isolation" is something that can only be defined between two things, and the datasheet neglects to say which two things – that datasheet really isn't a good datasheet, and you should just ask that company.

Anyway, usually, the most important isolation in a monostatic radar system is the one between transmit and receive direction, and I'd assume that's what they mean here, even if, and I repeat that, *this is pure speculation, because the datasheet is unusably vague*.

Comment: Looking at the mechanical images in the spec, I see only one port. Shouldn't there be at least two port, one for transmitter and other for receiver if we talk about isolation?

Comment: To repeat in full clarity: Shitty datasheet. Can't tell you what is meant. Ask manufacturer for better datasheet, not me.

Answer (score 1):

There may be circulators, or precision waveguide functions, that provide 85dB isolation.

[If megawatt pulses (+90 dBm), such isolation still allows +5dBm into the receiver. Thermal floor is about -100dBm.]

Or ionizable gas section in the waveguide, that become plasma when hit by high energy of the TX pulse.

Comment: that answers where the isolation might come from, but the original question was "what does it **mean**".

Comment: I appreciated. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the manufacturer is referring to if you had two identical antennas that are spaced 18 inches apart (measured from their centerlines) and are both facing the same direction (not towards each other), you will measure 85 dB isolation between them. That is, if you attach the antennas to a VNA, you would see S21 = S12 <= -85 dB.

I agree with Marcus however in that the datasheet is not clear at all. I would confirm this with the manufacturer.

This is a configuration you would use in radar, having separate antennas for transmit and receive, in order to obtain the required isolation between your high power transmit path and sensitive receiver. A circulator can be used, but they have limited isolation (no way you'd get 85 dB with a single circulator). Switches can also be used, but they do not allow for CW radar (e.g. FMCW) and are typically used in pulse radar.

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  The key may be what the acronym "OFR" means in the data sheet.  "Over the Field of Regard"?

Comment: @SteveSh If I had to guess, it would be "Operating Frequency Range" since the phrase is used in the first line of the electrical specifications. Though I'm sure one could come up with many possibilities...

Answer (score 0):

They are selling it as single antenna. It can be used as the transmitter and the receiver. The customer would do the mounting to a radar system. If you place them 18 inches apart from each other in the same plane, the antennas will have 85 dB antenna isolation. Meaning that the amount how much signal is received in one antenna when the other is transmitting.

Still not a great datasheet, and before building a radar it's something you must confirm from the manufacturer.